# concatenate if inline eval is not nothing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, eval

I have a data list with an item template that displays two values with a space between them. The issue is, when the first value is empty, there is a leading empty space. What I would like to do is only concatenate the space if there is a value in the first eval.

```
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Container.DataItem("CustomText")%>&nbsp;
                    <%#Container.DataItem("ServiceDescription")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

I want something like:

```
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#" " + Container.DataItem("CustomText")%>&nbsp;
                    <%#Container.DataItem("ServiceDescription")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

Where it only process any of the first <%# %> if there is a value for CustomText.

Make sense? I like it to have the leading &NBSP; because it allows it to offset the start of multi line descriptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<%# " " + If(IsDBNull(Container.DataItem("CustomText")) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(Container.DataItem("CustomText")), String.Empty, String.Format("{0}&nbsp;", Container.DataItem("CustomText"))) & Container.DataItem("ServiceDescription") %>
```

Comment: Fantastic and elegant, Thank you. I don't understand inline code as well as I would like.

Comment: You should use the `IF` operator instead of the `IIF` function in VB.NET

Comment: @MattWilko - Thanks for the suggestion! I didn't know that operator. I updated my answer.